# How do I apply compound growth formula to a Pandas Dataframe that contains negative values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas multi indexed dataframe that I would like to compute a compound growth on.  But some of the values in the column are negative.  If the first or the last values are negative, then the compound formula can fail to compute. What is the best way to get a compound growth over, say 3,5,7,10 years, in a case like this?  I am thinking maybe shift my start point away from any negative values to the first positive value, and adjust my endpoint from any negative number, to an average of the last n positive values, but I am open to other suggestions.

I am stumped on how actually to implement a solution.  I just know I've heard iterating a dataframe is anti pattern and I should be able to accomplish this without having to resort to iteration.

```
   import pandas as pd
   from pandas import Timestamp
   
   stocks =pd.DataFrame({
   'Ticker': {83: 'AAPL', 84: 'AAPL', 85: 'AAPL', 86: 'AAPL', 87: 'AAPL', 88: 'AAPL', 89: 'AAPL', 90: 'AAPL', 91: 'AAPL', 92: 'AAPL', 93: 'AAPL', 94: 'AAPL', 95: 'AAPL', 96: 'AAPL', 97: 'AAPL', 98: 'AAPL', 99: 'AAPL', 100: 'AAPL', 101: 'AAPL', 102: 'AAPL', 103: 'AAPL'}, 
   'Report Date': {83: Timestamp('2000-09-30 00:00:00'), 84: Timestamp('2001-09-30 00:00:00'), 85: Timestamp('2002-09-30 00:00:00'), 86: Timestamp('2003-09-30 00:00:00'), 87: Timestamp('2004-09-30 00:00:00'), 88: Timestamp('2005-09-30 00:00:00'), 89: Timestamp('2006-09-30 00:00:00'), 90: Timestamp('2007-09-30 00:00:00'), 91: Timestamp('2008-09-30 00:00:00'), 92: Timestamp('2009-09-30 00:00:00'), 93: Timestamp('2010-09-30 00:00:00'), 94: Timestamp('2011-09-30 00:00:00'), 95: Timestamp('2012-09-30 00:00:00'), 96: Timestamp('2013-09-30 00:00:00'), 97: Timestamp('2014-09-30 00:00:00'), 98: Timestamp('2015-09-30 00:00:00'), 99: Timestamp('2016-09-30 00:00:00'), 100: Timestamp('2017-09-30 00:00:00'), 101: Timestamp('2018-09-30 00:00:00'), 102: Timestamp('2019-09-30 00:00:00'), 103: Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00')}, 
   'Fiscal Year': {83: 2000, 84: 2001, 85: 2002, 86: 2003, 87: 2004, 88: 2005, 89: 2006, 90: 2007, 91: 2008, 92: 2009, 93: 2010, 94: 2011, 95: 2012, 96: 2013, 97: 2014, 98: 2015, 99: 2016, 100: 2017, 101: 2018, 102: 2019, 103: 2020}, 
   'Earnings Per Share': {83: 0, 84: -1.031721589159224, 85: -3.6019417475728153, 86: 0.06343283582089554, 87: 2.856140350877193, 88: 3.991810737033667, 89: 0.4976303317535544, 90: 0.7576679649464462, 91: 0.716570874593172, 92: 0.3285731574488686, 93: 0.6708872290034611, 94: 0.8202220647295062, 95: 0.591763590076374, 96: -0.10342513437741085, 97: 0.1354399121364962, 98: 0.4294251740496582, 99: -0.10014223524848076, 100: 0.10974920488945084, 101: 0.2962851063278793, 102: -0.003962242162918184, 103: 0.10601547744404893},
   })
```

_

```
                           Fiscal Year       Earnings Per Share 
  Ticker   Report Date                                     
  A        ...               ...                 ...
  AAPL     2000-09-30        2000                     <NA> 
           2001-09-30        2001                -1.031722 
           2002-09-30        2002                -3.601942 
           2003-09-30        2003                 0.063433 
           2004-09-30        2004                  2.85614 
           2005-09-30        2005                 3.991811 
           2006-09-30        2006                  0.49763 
           2007-09-30        2007                 0.757668 
           2008-09-30        2008                 0.716571 
           2009-09-30        2009                 0.328573 
           2010-09-30        2010                 0.670887 
           2011-09-30        2011                 0.820222 
           2012-09-30        2012                 0.591764 
           2013-09-30        2013                -0.103425 
           2014-09-30        2014                  0.13544 
           2015-09-30        2015                 0.429425 
           2016-09-30        2016                -0.100142 
           2017-09-30        2017                 0.109749 
           2018-09-30        2018                 0.296285 
           2019-09-30        2019                -0.003962 
           2020-09-30        2020                 0.106015 
  AAWW     2010-12-31        2010                 0.125432
           ...               ...                  ...
```

This is what I would like the result to look like(with made up values):

```
                           Fiscal Year       Earnings Per Share  10y Compounded Growth
  Ticker   Report Date                                     
           ...               ...                  ...                ...
  A        2020-12-31        2020                 0.49253            0.132
  AAPL     2000-09-30        2000                     <NA>           <NA>
           2001-09-30        2001                -1.031722           <NA>
           2002-09-30        2002                -3.601942           <NA>
           2003-09-30        2003                 0.063433           <NA>
           2004-09-30        2004                  2.85614           <NA>
           2005-09-30        2005                 3.991811           <NA>
           2006-09-30        2006                  0.49763           <NA>
           2007-09-30        2007                 0.757668           <NA>
           2008-09-30        2008                 0.716571           <NA>
           2009-09-30        2009                 0.328573           0.234
           2010-09-30        2010                 0.670887           0.234
           2011-09-30        2011                 0.820222           0.234
           2012-09-30        2012                 0.591764           0.234
           2013-09-30        2013                -0.103425           0.234
           2014-09-30        2014                  0.13544           0.234
           2015-09-30        2015                 0.429425           0.234
           2016-09-30        2016                -0.100142           0.234
           2017-09-30        2017                 0.109749           0.234
           2018-09-30        2018                 0.296285           0.234
           2019-09-30        2019                -0.003962           0.234
           2020-09-30        2020                 0.106015           0.234
  AAWW     2010-12-31        2010                 0.125432           0.234
           ...               ...                  ...                ...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please reduce the scope of this dataframe into a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: Also please include your expected output, as this can be very helpful when testing solutions, not only to determine what form the output should take, but also to have something to compare against to confirm that the solution is working as expected.